# Are the indices in an OpenMP loop processed in ascending order?

Tags: c++, c, openmp

Consider the following OpenMP for loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    //do something with i
}
```

Is it guaranteed that each OpenMP thread sees its i values in ascending order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order in which threads run is not guaranteed; **the order in which a thread processes its own chunk is guaranteed**.

Answer (score 4):

If your question is if each thread will get a chunk of the iteration and if within that chunk the value of `i` is sequential, then the answer is yes. Is that your question?

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to know!